# How to detect the Snipping Tool in Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, windows-7

How to detect process of Snipping Tool in Windows 7 without using a timer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to monitor process creation (and much more). [This blog entry](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/delphi-and-wmi-events/#Tag3) will get you started using WMI from Delphi describing the events you might want to monitor. This works without using timers.

An alternative would be diving into the world of [hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [Monitoring window creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299370/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-make-my-wh-shell-or-wh-cbt-hook-procedure-receive-events) will also reveal the Snipping Tool being started. This could fail though if some application [fails to use CallNextHookEx properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487807/global-wh-cbt-hook-dll-is-loaded-into-some-processes-only).